# versioning dlls in TFS 2017

Tags: build, versioning

I want to version my dlls, exe in my build process. I followed [this](https://writeabout.net/2015/11/01/set-assembly-and-app-version-to-a-matching-build-name-in-tfs-2015-or-vso-build-vnext/). He said that i should have "Build Number Format".

I do not have "General" tab in build definition in TFS 2017. How do I version my dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then tutorial is using TFS2015 version, and there has been a General tab in build definition on that version.

> Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2017.1 and older
>
> The section is available under General tab.

For later version you could find the **[Build number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#build-number-format)** on  the build definition **Options** tab.
[image]

For more details about version number, you could also take a look at this great post: [TFS Build 2015 … and versioning](https://intovsts.net/2015/08/24/tfs-build-2015-and-versioning/)! and this similar topic [vNext Build Awesomeness – Managing Version Numbers](http://blogs.incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/)